# Bootstrap trigger event tab show when click next button

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

Can anyone help me, i have code like these on jquery

```
$('#nexttab').click(function () {
            var tabToShow = $(this).attr("data-target");
            if ($(tabToShow).length) {
                $('a[href="' + tabToShow + '"]').tab('show');           
                
                $( "#scannerinput" ).focus();
                $('#scannerinput').keyup(function(){
                    var barcode = $(this).val();
                    var judul = $(this).attr("data-judul");
                    var dataString = "judul=" + judul + "&barcode=" + barcode;
                    if(this.value.length ==12){
                        $.ajax
                        ({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: url+"process",
                            data: dataString,
                            cache: false,
                            success: function(data)
                            {
                                $( "#scannerinput" ).focus();
                                $( "#scannerinput" ).val('');
                                $( "#blank_barcode" ).hide();
                                $("#barcode_info").text(barcode);
                                $("#info_barcode").html(data);
                            }
                        });
                        //$( "#scannerinput" ).blur(); 
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

But my problem, every time i click the button next tab, my input not focusing and `keyup()` function not working too. How do i suppose my input focusing and `keyup()` function working properly?

Comment: Use console.log

Comment: @FSDford i try that not working too

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code, Your If condition is not correct.

**From**

```
if ($(tabToShow).length) {

}
```

**To**

```
if (tabToShow.length > 0) {
  //Your Logic Here
}
```

Comment: still not working on my focusing input. :(

Answer (score 0):

Never mind i found it!!
I just doin like these

```
$('#nexttab').click(function () {
                var tabToShow = $(this).attr("data-target");
                if (tabToShow.length > 0) {
                    $('a[href="' + tabToShow + '"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
                        $( "#scannerinput" ).focus();
                        $('#scannerinput').keyup(function(){
                            var barcode = $(this).val();
                            var judul = $(this).attr("data-judul");
                            var dataString = "judul=" + judul + "&barcode=" + barcode;
                            if(this.value.length ==12){
                                $.ajax
                                ({
                                    type: "POST",
                                    url: url+"process",
                                    data: dataString,
                                    cache: false,
                                    success: function(data)
                                    {
                                        $( "#scannerinput" ).focus();
                                        $( "#scannerinput" ).val('');
                                        $( "#blank_barcode" ).hide();
                                        $("#barcode_info").text(barcode);
                                        $("#info_barcode").html(data);
                                    }
                                });
                                //$( "#scannerinput" ).blur(); 
                            }
                        });
                    }).tab('show');
                }
            });
```

It working perfectly. :)